# I have many solution files in one repository, i want all solution files to restore using nuget ina single command

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have many solution files in one repository, i want all solution files to restore using nuget using a single command.

Or is there any other way instead of giving all solution file names one by one

eg:

Nuget restore solution1.sln

Nuget restore solution2.sln

Nuget restore solution3.sln

i tried below command but no luck

nuget restore **'\'*.sln

Comment: Expanding *'s or **'s is called globbing. nuget.exe doesn't support globbing, or even passing multiple projects or solutions in a single command. You'll need to use a shell script instead.

Comment: Thanks @zivkan , I have one more question. When i build solution file using MSBuild where does the built o/p will save ?

Comment: The same place as if you built each project individually, or the same place as where Visual Studio writes the output files, whichever you're more familiar with. By default it's in the `bin/` folder, created in the same folder as your `csproj` file.